# Using LSTMs to predict from single-element sequence

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm, reinforcement-learning

I'm trying to apply reinforcement learning to a round-based game environment. Each round I get a (self-contained / nearly markovian) state and have to provide an action to progress in the world. Because there exist some long-term strategies (develop resource "A", wait few rounds for development, use resource "A"), I'm thinking of using an LSTM layer in my neural net. During training I can feed sequences of rounds into the network to train the LSTM; however, during the testing phase I'm only able to provide the current state (this is a hard requirement).

I'm wondering whether LSTMs are a viable option here or if they are not suitable for this usage, because I can only provide one state during testing / deployment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, LSTMs are a viable option here. In keras this would surmount to setting the field called "stateful" to true. What this does is to *not* reset the internal state of the cells between each sample, meaning that it would keep remembering the previous step(s) until this cell is reset.

In this case, you would simply set the LSTM stateful to true, hand it one sample per step and reset after the episode is done. Remember that you might not want to keep it stateful during training if there is enough signal that you can fit all the timesteps you need for finding the long term strategies into one sample, as you'd probably be doing replays over multiple episodes.

IF you're using anything else but keras, googling for stateful LSTM in xyz framework ought to help you further